# Why does a radio's tank circuit frequency match the emitted EM wave freqency?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radio

I am trying to understand some of the specifics of RF radiation. I am concerned with the normal antenna-emitted EM waves, no relativistic charges, no Bremsstrahlung involved.

The tuning of a tank circuit (the arising oscillation frequency) determines the frequency of the EM wave emitted.

But how is an electric oscillation's frequency linked to the emitted photon's frequency? The first one has noting to do with energy, at least not directly. The other one is directly linked to energy, it determines the energy of the photon.

Is there a calculation demonstrating that the energy emitted as a result of electron acceleration/deceleration (oscillation) results in a photon with the same frequency?

Shouldn't the strength of the electric field accelerating the charge also come into play when determining the energy emitted? Then does it impact the frequency of the photon emitted?

Comment: If you are vibrating charges at some frequency $f$, causing a fluctuating electromagnetic field, how do you envision the EM wave not having that same frequency $f$?

Comment: for radio frequencies, it is customary and convenient to deal with radiation in terms of waves and not photons. you'll avoid unnecessary confusion that way IMHO.

Comment: @nielsnielsen The OP is asking how to reconcile two ways of thinking about radiation. Answering "don't bother" isn't really an answer.

Comment: @davidsank, that's why I posted it as a comment expressing an opinion and not as an answer. If I can come up with an answer that directly addresses the content of his question, I will post it as such. That would require me to furnish a concise explanation of where the photon and wave pictures yield equally useful descriptions which I'm not sure I can manage before starting to cook dinner.

Comment: @DanielSank, You are right, that is the essence of my question. I am disturbed by the (I presume "seemingly") alternative ways EM radiation can be induced. For low energies (low freqencies) it is sufficient to place a charge in an oscillating field. For high energies it is usually the inelastic collision of the charge and loss of speed/momentum. The second one seems more straightforward to me since the energy of the photon emitted (that is, its freqency) is related to the energy loss of the charge.

Comment: In the first case however, the frequency (again, the photon's energy) seemingly comes from the field's oscillation and not, as I would expect, from the acceleration/deceleration  of the charge. I think that this should only be a very good approximation for low energies of the Bremsstrahlung, and I would like to see something to prove/disprove that.

Comment: *"Is there a calculation demonstrating that the energy emitted as a result of electron acceleration/deceleration (oscillation) results in a photon with the same frequency?"* Yes, we could write that up here if that would really answer your question. However, I have a feeling that it wouldn't.

Comment: @DanielSank, Still, if you find the time, I would be very interested. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so what *exactly* do you want? I could write the mathematics of a charge coupled to the electromagnetic field and show that the oscillation frequency of the charge maps to the frequency of generated photons. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DanielSank, Since I believe all that you have already written and I do not think I could effectively digest all the math you are ready to share with me let's cut some corners. I would be happy to see one or two factual calculatios like: an electron is placed in an oscillating field of frequency f, oscillates between two extremes x A away from each other, experiences acceleration / deceleration of a, and hence radiates energy of E. And that matches a photon of freqency f due to the formula of photon energy. And then, if there are any, mention the limiting factors. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Groovy. Are you familiar with Hamiltonian mechanics?

Comment: That would be an exaggeration. However, should the figures add up, I promise I will read very carefully.

Comment: @DanielSank, I really do not want to be pushy. Is there a simple way to conclude or should I abandon this question?

Comment: I've just been busy and answering questions like this takes some focus. I wouldn't abandon the question if I were you. It's a good question.

Comment: Fine, thanks. I will check back to see the developments.